# PHP multidimensional array foreach not work

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array. i want to get every photosArray as a unique item.such as example: in my Facebook i post a image if i post single image then photosArray have one item but if i post multiple image in a post then photosArray have multiple item.

now i want to print all post photo how.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [photosArray] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [__type] => File
                                    [name] => e24da5a6-e5a1-4d91-a8c7-64d046759382-file
                                    [url] => http://files.parse.com/c2dcf728-e2a3-4b2d-a8c8-6ec9b3c6502a/e24da5a6-e5a1-4d91-a8c7-64d046759382-file
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [__type] => File
                                    [name] => e4029a4a-e928-4afd-8cf1-3a9084e40126-file
                                    [url] => http://files.parse.com/c2dcf728-e2a3-4b2d-a8c8-6ec9b3c6502a/e4029a4a-e928-4afd-8cf1-3a9084e40126-file
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [__type] => File
                                    [name] => 5b7e30c7-7283-4115-b177-08e5652f80b1-file
                                    [url] => http://files.parse.com/c2dcf728-e2a3-4b2d-a8c8-6ec9b3c6502a/5b7e30c7-7283-4115-b177-08e5652f80b1-file
                                )

                        )


                    [createdAt] => 2014-04-20T13:49:00.012Z
                    [updatedAt] => 2014-04-20T13:49:00.012Z
                    [postid] => 12

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [photosArray] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [__type] => File
                                    [name] => d77c7975-bf50-4a2c-ad9e-975d2cd4c47b-file
                                    [url] => http://files.parse.com/c2dcf728-e2a3-4b2d-a8c8-6ec9b3c6502a/d77c7975-bf50-4a2c-ad9e-975d2cd4c47b-file
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [__type] => File
                                    [name] => 730110b0-980b-4e40-be07-81509cb91efa-file
                                    [url] => http://files.parse.com/c2dcf728-e2a3-4b2d-a8c8-6ec9b3c6502a/730110b0-980b-4e40-be07-81509cb91efa-file
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [__type] => File
                                    [name] => 9f246b77-cdf5-409c-8a99-5a0188dbcca9-file
                                    [url] => http://files.parse.com/c2dcf728-e2a3-4b2d-a8c8-6ec9b3c6502a/9f246b77-cdf5-409c-8a99-5a0188dbcca9-file
                                )

                        )


                    [createdAt] => 2014-04-20T13:57:08.231Z
                    [updatedAt] => 2014-04-20T13:57:08.231Z
                    [postid] => 112

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [photosArray] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [__type] => File
                                    [name] => 2c85f3be-69d8-4ca1-be51-8848bb73eb78-file
                                    [url] => http://files.parse.com/c2dcf728-e2a3-4b2d-a8c8-6ec9b3c6502a/2c85f3be-69d8-4ca1-be51-8848bb73eb78-file
                                )

                        )


                    [createdAt] => 2014-04-21T07:45:52.829Z
                    [updatedAt] => 2014-04-21T07:45:52.829Z
                    [postid] => 172

                )





            [3] => Array
                (
                    [photosArray] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [__type] => File
                                    [name] => 6fd7458f-0ade-4bc6-9567-04c6bc197ea3-file
                                    [url] => http://files.parse.com/c2dcf728-e2a3-4b2d-a8c8-6ec9b3c6502a/6fd7458f-0ade-4bc6-9567-04c6bc197ea3-file
                                )

                        )

                    [createdAt] => 2014-04-21T07:45:52.829Z
                    [updatedAt] => 2014-04-21T07:45:52.829Z

                )

        )

)
```

I am trying this code but its not work

```
foreach($specified_post_photo_array AS $item)
{


    foreach($item['photosArray'] AS $pitem)
    {
        $photo=$pitem['url'];



    }

}
```

But Its show no result

Comment: [Enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) first.

Comment: no error show @AmalMurali

Comment: You're only traversing through the second level of your multi-demensional array. You need to go one level deeper to access `$item['photosArray']`

Comment: Logic: `FOREACH(ARRAY AS A){ FOREACH(A AS A_1) { FOREACH(A_1 AS ITEM) { echo ITEM; } } }`

Comment: Or as Marcins' answer suggests!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change your code into:

```
foreach($specified_post_photo_array[0] AS $item)
{


    foreach($item['photosArray'] AS $pitem)
    {
        $photo=$pitem['url'];



    }

}
```

Comment: if i want to separate as single item which   [photosArray] have multiple item then what can i do @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
$specified_post_photo_array = $specified_post_photo_array[0];

foreach($specified_post_photo_array as $key => $value)
{
   echo '<br> Photo 1 : '. $value['photosArray'][0]['url'];
   echo '<br> Photo 2 : '. $value['photosArray'][1]['url'];
   echo '<br> Photo 3 : '. $value['photosArray'][2]['url']; 
}
```

Hope this helps..!!